# How to perform case insensitive str_contains?

Tags: php, php-8

I have plenty of `if(mb_stripos($hay, $needle) !== false)` in my code. How do I replace it with [`str_contains()`](https://wiki.php.net/rfc/str_contains)?

For example, I have this helper function in my code:

```
<?php

function str_contains_old(string $hay, string $needle): bool
{
    return mb_stripos($hay, $needle) !== false;
}

$str1 = 'Hello world!';
$str2 = 'hello';
var_dump(str_contains_old($str1, $str2)); // gives bool(true)

$str1 = 'Część';
$str2 = 'cZĘŚĆ';
var_dump(str_contains_old($str1, $str2)); // gives bool(true)

$str1 = 'Część';
$str2 = 'czesc';
var_dump(str_contains_old($str1, $str2)); // gives bool(false)
```

How to make it work with new [`str_contains()`](https://wiki.php.net/rfc/str_contains)?

```
var_dump(str_contains('Hello world!', 'hello')); // gives bool(false)
```

[Demo](https://3v4l.org/lprsk)

Comment: Considering thats not out yet (looks like it even got pulled from the php manual site??) .... its behavior may change by the time its implemented. Last I read "there is no case insensitive variant".

Comment: Worst case scenario here, is you either continue using the stripos as we have been doing for decades... or wrap the inputs in `strtolower()` so its comparing two identical case'd strings :( Both equally as ugly.

Comment: It may be added in the future: "Concerning the case-insensitivity for this function: This might be a feature for the future"

Comment: Yes, Stack Overflow, this is a released function as of PHP8 https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.str-contains.php

Answer (score 14, accepted):

You want a case-insensitive version of `str_contains()`
The short answer is: There isn't one.

The long answer is: case-sensitivity is encoding and locale dependent. By the time you've added those are information to a hypothetical `str_icontains()`, you've recreated `mb_stripos()`.  TL;DR - Don't do it.

Comment: This seems like questionable advice. What exactly do you think `str_contains()` is if not `mb_strpos()` that returns a bool?

Comment: exposed here : https://php.watch/versions/8.0/str_contains

Answer (score 18):

Just convert both string and haystack to lowercase beforehand

```
$string = strtolower($originalString);
$haystack = strtolower($originalHaystack);
$isMatched = str_contains($originalHaystack,$originalString);
```

Comment: Thanks! But the last line should be: $isMatched = str_contains($haystack, $string);

Comment: Sometimes the answer to some problems is so simple, yet I need to stackoverflow it and then the light bulb goes on :) Thanks!

Comment: This code is wrong, last line should not have the original strings.