# startsWith Case sensitive

Tags: php, case-insensitive, startswith

Can't find a solution to this which seems simple enough. I have user input field and want to check the user has prefixed the code asked for with an S (example code S123456 so I want to check to make sure they didn't just put 123456).

```
// Function to check string starting with s

if (isset($_REQUEST['submitted'])) { $string=$_POST['required_code'];function startsWith ($string, $startString){$len = strlen($startString);return (substr($string, 0, $len) === $startString);
}
  
// Do the check 
if(startsWith($string, "s"))echo "Code starts with a s";else echo "Code does not start with a s";}
```

The problem is if the user inputs an upper case S this is seen as not being a lower case s.

So I can get round this using

```
$string = strtolower($string);
```

So if the user inputs an uppercase S it gets converted to lower case before the check. But is this the best way? Is there not someway to say S OR s?
Any suggestions?

Comment: That Code tag thing doesn't seem to work here. I put the code in the required tags using Ctrl K but it's not come out right.

Comment: To mark a _block_ of text as code, you need to use _three_ "backticks", or indent _all_ the lines of the code; see https://stackoverflow.com/editing-help#code I've fixed your post for you, you can see what I edited here: https://stackoverflow.com/posts/73373408/revisions

Comment: the way you check it is best practice, to my knowledge. Just set the string to check and the input string to the same - either upper or lowercase and you're fine

Comment: There are case-insensitive recommendations at [the canonical page](https://stackoverflow.com/q/834303/2943403) and the duplicates which point to it.  Here is [a related topic](https://stackoverflow.com/q/63121737/2943403).

Comment: If you are validating the user input, why not validate the entire input at the same time? `preg_match('/^S\d+$/', $input)`  If the goal is to sanitize the string then you could do something like `$sanitized = preg_replace('/^\D*(\d+).*/s', 'S$1', $input, 1, $count);` which would sanitize the input and `if ($count)` would mean that the input contained at least one digit.  Standardizing/Sanitizing user input is a fundamental technique that will ensure that subsequent processes can run seamlessly.

Answer (score 4):

What you could do instead of creating your own function, is using [stripos](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.stripos.php). Stripos tries to find the first occurrence of a case-insensitive substring.

So as check you could have:

```
if(stripos($string, "s") === 0)
```

You need 3 equal signs, since stripos will return false (0) if it can't find the substring.

Answer (score 3):

Take your pick; there are many ways to see if a string starts with 'S'. Some of them case-sensitive, some not. The options below should all work, although I wouldn't consider any of them better than your current solution. `stripos()` is probably the 'cleanest' check though. If you need multibyte support, there's also the `mb_stripos()` variant.

(Although; keep in mind that `stripos()` can also return `false`. If you're going with that option, **always** use the stricter "identical" operator `===`, instead of `==` to prevent type juggling.)

```
if (stripos($string, 's') === 0) {
    // String starts with S or s
} else {
    // It does not
}
```

```
if (str_starts_with($string, 's') || str_starts_with($string, 'S')) // ...
```

```
if (in_array(substr($string, 0, 1), ['S', 's'], true)) // ...
```

```
if (preg_match('/^s/i', $string)) // ...
// Many other regexp patterns also work
```

Comment: for regex you can also use the insenstive flag i.e. `preg_match('/^s/i')`

Comment: Note that when it comes to case sensitivity, "multibyte support" opens up a whole can of worms - Is "ß" a case-insensitive match for "ss", or perhaps for "sz"? How to handle [the two forms of i in Turkish](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dotted_and_dotless_I_in_computing)? And so on. The most comprehensive approach is to use the ICU's collation definitions, implemented in PHP as [the Collation class](https://www.php.net/manual/en/class.collator.php) in the intl extension.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks all, it was

```
if (str_starts_with($string, 's') || str_starts_with($string, 'S')) // ...
```

I was looking for I had tried

```
if (str_starts_with($string, 's' || 'S')) // ...
```